# Does a class being its own delegate follow iOS convention?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

Sorry this question may sound "subjective" but I think it should have a pretty definitive answer. I have a class "LocationManager" that I want to manage my Core Location logic. I have two options:

1. LocationManager has a strong property referencing an instance of CLLocationManager. LocationManager is a delegate of CLLocationManager and receives location updates from it as such.
2. LocationManager is a subclass of CLLocationManager, and says self.delegate = self so that it can receive its own location updates.

I'm curious which of these options is considered the "right" thing to do, I'm sure that there must a be a preferred way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Subclassing `CLLocationManager` and setting its delegate to self should not be done because it breaks the contract of `CLLocationManager`. As the class is currently defined, it has a `delegate` property. This property serves as a contract which states that you may set this property to some other object, and this object will receive delegate notifications. If you subclass `CLLocationManager` (let's call it `MyLocationManager`), and if the delegate property of the object points to itself, then you will most likely create a situation where `MyLocationManager` only works as promised if the user does *not* use the `delegate` property for his own purposes. From a users point of view, `MyLocationManager` is a `CLLocationManager` without a usable `delegate` property. This violates [Liskovs Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), btw. The question to ask here is: would `MyLocationManager` still work, if some `ViewController` class decides to use it and have its `delegate` property point to itself (the `ViewController`)?

Furthermore, it is no longer "delegation", if you say `self.delegate = self`. So I would say it is preferrable to use variant 1.

Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do this with no problem.  I've a subclass of UITextField which is its own delegate.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. It completely subverts the whole delegate design pattern. See Michael's answer, above.

Comment: Well I don't know if it's the best practice in the world, and in this particular case its difficult to see any benefit, but i disagree about this violating Liskov's Substitution Principle.  If the OP was to create a subclass of CLLocationManager which is set to be its own delegate this does not of itself break this subclass' ability to perform when/if its delegate is subsequently set to some other object, so this subclass should still be able to perform as a CLLocationManager..  It has only been extended to implement the protocol in addition to its own API..

Comment: @Jef: the OP didn't ask if it is possible to set a delegate to self, he rather asks if it follows iOS-convention to do so. And I didn't say that pointing a delegate property to self violates LSP automatically; I just said that in practice, it's hard to create a situation where a delegate points to self that does not violate LSP. I know it seems like hair-splitting, but I anticipated this discussion, and for that reason I formulated my original answer in the way I did. In any case, the conclusion should be IMHO that pointing a delegate to self should be avoided in most cases.

Comment: I think, pointing a delegate to self does in most cases violate LSP, but if it does not, it still breaks the contract of delegation. Delegation is a composition technic designed to make an object extendable without needing to subclass it. Subclassing it anyways seems fishy to me. For me, the delegation contract seems to imply: "these are the functions that I cannot implement. It's your (the delegate's) task to do that". And a subclass that points its delegate to self is saying: "I know better than my parent class". So I agree with @DuncanC that it would subvert the delegate design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The first option seems right to me because it doesn't make a ton of sense to subclass `CLLocationManager` (#2). What functionality would you be adding to it? If you're not adding anything to it why subclass?

All you care about is encapsulating the messages about location updates. I'd say you're using the delegate/protocol pattern acceptably in the first case.

And Jef is right, there are times where a subclass of another class can be set as its own delegate. Though you need to be careful about how that object responds to certain messages.