# Capture delegate methods from UITextField subclass without being the delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter, uitextfielddelegate

I have a `UITextField` subclass. I needed to know when text did change and I was able to get that with `NotificationCenter` and observing `.UITextFieldTextDidChange` but now I need to know when the user tap return button. The only solution that I can think about it is setting the `UITextField` subclass to be the delegate of it self, but it sound not clean.

1. Is there a clean way to get the return key event from subclass
2. Is it Ok to to set the `UITextField` subclass to be the delegate of it self ?

Comment: May I ask you why you need that?

Comment: I'm currently using the 'UITextFieldDelegate' where I'm setting the delegate to the appropriate textField(s), where the RETURN button needs to be identified. You can then identify with 'func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool' if the return button was tapped. Nevertheless, I'm not 100% sure if this is the cleanest solution.

Comment: There is an interesting discussion of the second point of your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29054602/does-a-class-being-its-own-delegate-follow-ios-convention

Comment: @Andrea Trying to make the textField adapted to be used as search text field, I ended up putting the textField in a UIView and make that view the delegate the good thing about that is that I can hide the textfield (`private`) and expose what is only needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your subclass do

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(returnKeyPressed), for: .editingDidEndOnExit);
```

Looking at Apples doc you see UIControlEvents

> UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,     // 'return key' ending editing

Comment: Good to know. That answer the question. But I ended up wrapping the textField in a `UIView` and make it the delegate of `UITextField` which can be `private`

Answer (score 1):

Simply duplicate `UITextFieldDelegate` with a new protocol and pass the calls from `UITextFieldDelegate` through the custom delegate to the view controller.

First, create a new protocol with whichever delegate methods you want to pass through to the view controller.

```
protocol CustomTextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField)
}
```

Then, set the delegate of the subclass to `self`, and whenever those methods are called (within the subclass), do what you need with them and then pass them along to the custom delegate.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    var customDelegate: CustomTextFieldDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        delegate = self
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        return nil
    }
}

extension CustomTextField: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {

        // Do what you need in the subclass.

        // When done, pass the call along to the custom delegate.
        customDelegate?.textFieldDidChangeSelection(textField)
    }
}
```

And the view controller will be able to use the delegate as if this pass-through wasn't there.

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    let someTextField = CustomTextField()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        someTextField.customDelegate = self
    }
}

extension SomeViewController: CustomTextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // Do work
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set your viewController to be the delegate. In `viewDidLoad` you can add this line of code.

```
myTextField.delegate = self
```

You also need the UITextFieldDelegate protocol for the viewController.

```
extension MyViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        //User tapped the return button
        return true
    }
}
```

I think there is nothing wrong with setting the delegate to the subclass. If you need to know the tap outside of your class then you will need another delegate so you might as well use my first solution. You should also be aware that if you change the delegate your code in the subclass will not be called anymore and it could lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: What you wrote is prefectly fine, he was asking what he can do inside of his `UITextField` subclass, and there its not recommended to use the delegate, since user of the subclass like one you mentioned above `MyViewController` would like to be the delegate :)

Comment: I was asking about make the textField it self the delegate something like: 
`textField.delegate = self` but I am aware that the ViewController can be the delegate

Comment: I answered both of his questions. The first one does not ask for anything inside his subclass. It asks for a clean solution and I think setting the ViewController as a delegate is a clean solution.